# subir imagenes desde angular 9 a laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, angular

Intento subir varias imagenes desde angular a laravel, mi codigo del servicio en angular es:

```
  crearInvProducto( invProducto: any ) {   
    const formData = new FormData();

    for(let key in invProducto){  
      formData.append(key, invProducto[key])
    }
    
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'
      });
      this.http.post(`${ URL }/invproductos`, formData, {headers})
          .subscribe( resp => {           
            console.log(resp);
                             
            if (resp['code'] === 200) {
              //this.nuevoCarrito.emit( resp['carrito'] );              
              resolve(resp);            
            } else {
              resolve(resp['msj']);
            }
          });
    });
  }
```

y el codigo en laravel eliminando algunas lineas es:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $datos = array(
        "titulo"                =>$request->input("titulo" ),
        "estado"                =>$request->input("estado"),
        "imagenPrincipal"       =>$request->input("imagenPrincipal"),
        "galeriaImagenes"       =>$request->input("galeriaImagenes"),
        "usuario_creador"       =>$request->input("usuario_creador"),
        "usuario_modificador"   =>$request->input("usuario_modificador")
    );

    $messages = [
         'required' => 'El campo :attribute es requerido.',
         'unique'   => 'El campo :attribute debe ser unico',
         'numeric'  => 'El campo :attribute debe ser numerico',
        //  'min'      => 'El campo :attribute debe tener minimo 10 caracteres',
        //  'max'      => 'El campo :attribute debe tener maximo 10 caracteres',
         ];

    $validator = validator($datos, [
        "titulo"                => 'required|string|min:10|max:500',
        "estado"                => 'required|string',

    ],$messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            return response()->json($errors->all());
        }else{
            
            if ($request->hasFile('imagenPrincipal')) { 
                $imagen = $request->file('imagenPrincipal');
                $nombreImagen = uniqid().'.'.$imagen->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $datos['imagenPrincipal']=$request->file('imagenPrincipal')->storeAs('uploads', 'productos/'.$nombreImagen, 'public');
            }       
            
            if (empty($request->galeriaImagenes) === false) { 
                
                $galeriaImagenes = [];
                $imagenes = $request->file("galeriaImagenes");
    
                foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) {
                    $nombreImagen = uniqid().'.'.$imagen->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $tempImage = $imagen->storeAs('uploads', 'productos/'.$nombreImagen, 'public');
                    array_push($galeriaImagenes, $tempImage);
                }
                $datos['galeriaImagenes']= $galeriaImagenes;
            } 
            InvProductos::create($datos);
            return $this->successResponse($datos);
        }
}
```

tengo 2 campos con imagenes un campo solo permite una imagen y el segundo multiples imagenes, la imagen del campo que tiene solo una imagen se guarda sin problemas pero el otro no. lo extraño es que si creo un formulario en html y envio multiples imagenes se guardan sin problemas, lo que me dice que el problema esta del lado de angular. probe con POSTMAN pero tampoco guarda varias imagenes, solo la del campo de una sola imagen.

este el formulario html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con este si logro guardarlas todas las imagenes.

esta es una imagen de el objeto que tiene las imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el servidor me da la siguiente respuesta cuando intento guardar desde angular:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero desde el formularion en html5 todo va de maravilla, por lo que definitivamente el problema esta del lado de angular.

Comment: ¿Qué código de retorno da el servidor web? ¿Qué tienes en el [método `authorize()` del `FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests)? Además, quizá deberías iterar `$request->galeriaImagenes` y no `$request->file('galeriaImagenes')`, que [obtiene únicamente un archivo](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html).

Comment: probe iterando en `$request->galeriaImagenes` y no funciona. no entra a la condicion `if ($request->hasFile('galeriaImagenes'))`

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer una prueba? Cambia esa comprobación de `if ($request->hasFile('galeriaImagenes')) {` por `if (empty($request->galeriaImagenes) === false) {`. Hará una comprobación doble, si existe la propiedad de clase y si contiene elementos (en caso de ser una matriz).

Comment: @OscarGarcia acabo de editar la pregunta con los cambios, desde angular me lanza un error pero desde el formulario HTML5 todo funciona bien, el problema es en angular.

Comment: Disculpa, esa excepción es debida a que PHP ha devuelto un error 500 (Internal server error), que significa que tu script PHP no pudo ejecutarse por algún motivo (quizá un error de sintaxis en el código). ¿Podrías revisar el log de error de apache para ver qué error hay?

Comment: ¿Pudiste mirar el mensaje de error en el log de error de Apache?

Comment: Sí, no era un error de sintaxisa, simplemente el foreach no podia iterar la informacion que le enviava, pude resolver el problema aplicando esta solucion a mi codigo: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034587/how-to-upload-multiple-images-files-in-angular-with-laravel-api/57056365#57056365]

Comment: Es otra solución diferente, pero con los pasos que te estaba indicando no era necesario hacer eso. Me alegra que se solucionara el problema. Si esta pregunta ya no necesita ser resuelta, por favor, pulsa en el enlace para eliminarla.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque ya ha sido solucionada con otro método alternativo